# How to get a mapped Url in Vite? Source map

Tags: vite, rollup, source-maps

I have not yet entered the world of plugins, but I have one idea and I want to test it as simple as possible.

**Question:**
I have a url WITHOUT SOURCE MAP, e.g. `instance/$$self.$$.update@http://localhost:5173/src/lib/ContextListItem.svelte:448:15`.
And I want to get from it a URL WITH SOURCE MAP, e.g. `http://localhost:5173/src/lib/ContextListItem.svelte:19:11`.
Theoretically it is a simple function:

```js
const mappedUrl = getMappedUrl(url)
```

How to get it in Vite?

**What do I need it for?**
I have such code:

```js
            window._log = console.log.bind(console);
            console.log = function (...a) {
                try {
                    throw Error("aa");
                } catch (err) {
                    const fileUrl =  err.stack.split("\n")[1].split("@")[1].replace(`${location.origin}/`,"").split(":")[0];
                    window._log(...a, `${location.origin}/__open-in-editor?file=${/* encodeURIComponent */(fileUrl)}`);
                }
            }
```

And I want (as you can see) to add a link to the location in the code (thanks to the method from `__open-in-editor`).
Here I am missing a specific line and column in the file.
[image]

In Microsoft Egde any link from the console can direct to VSCode, but unfortunately in other browsers this is not there (e.g. my bug for Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1771862).
[image: Microsoft Edge Workspaces]

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer, But it only works asynchronously, so it's not suitable for replacing console.log. :/

Use on the Web - https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/#use-on-the-web
Consuming a source map - https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/#consuming-a-source-map

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/source-map@0.7.3/dist/source-map.js"></script>
<script>
    sourceMap.SourceMapConsumer.initialize({
            "lib/mappings.wasm": "https://unpkg.com/source-map@0.7.3/lib/mappings.wasm"
    });
</script>
<script type="module">
    export async function aaa (origin, fileUrl, line, column) {
        const res = await fetch(`${origin}/${fileUrl}.map`);
        const json = await res.json();
        const place = await sourceMap.SourceMapConsumer.with(json, null, consumer => {
            
            const place = consumer.originalPositionFor({
                line: Number(line),
                column: Number(column)
            });
            return place;
        });
        return place;
    }
</script>
```